# Как визуализировать на с++ поэтапное изменение цветов квадратов? (с исп. openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, анимация

Работаю над клеточными автоматами. Есть двумерный массив, который после работы функции меняет значение некоторых элементов с 1 на 0 и наоборот. Программа должна (в идеале - по нажатию) выводить все элементы по порядку на экран в виде квадратов: 1 - красным, 0 - синим (к примеру).
Пыталась разобраться с openGL. Возможно ли это вообще сделать, используя его?

Comment: Да, возможно. Но OpenGL отвечает только за отображение, обработка нажатий делается другими средствами.

Answer (score 1):

Да это возможно, но в двух словах не ответишь. Чтобы реализовать полноценную отрисовку, вам придётся изучить OpenGL хотя бы базовые вещи.

В вашем случае, вы должны создать текстуру (или буффер) и отображать её. Причём перед отрисовкой обновлять данные в текстуре, используя ваш буфер. Правда сказать это не быстро для каждого кадра гонять данные из ОЗУ в видеопамять. Возможно вам если количество элементов не велико, то для каждого вашего элемента создаёте прямоугольник и отрисовываете их. В этом случае для каждого прямоугольника необходимо задавать каждый цвет. Из контекста вопроса не совсем понятно какой метод лучше.